# vim-7 with ctags

Tags: vim, vi, ctags

running VIM-7.0.237 on CentOS-5.6. I have a large C code base with tags generated with ctags-5.6, there are functions with the same name defined in several places and I remember back when I used vim-6.3, I could jump over those multiple definitions easily -- VIM used to suggest me what definition I want to jump at. Now with vim-7 it gives me only first.

Is there a way to have a old-style behavior? Thanks.

PS. I have a default VIM configuration.

Comment: In case you didn't know, `:tn` goes to the next definition.  I only recently started using Vim so never considered it working differently.

Comment: Thanks for advices. I normally used Ctrl-] to follow the tag and 'vim' suggested me a list of possible options to choose from. Perhaps the behavior of Ctrl-] in the new version has changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `g]` (`g$` on french azerty keyboards) to display a list of definitions.

Comment: thanks this also works. How can see what function is mapped on a specific key sequence?

Comment: Try `:map` without arguments to get a list of every single mapping available.

Answer (score 1):

You can either precede the command with a count to jump to a specific match or use
`:ts {identifier}`. It will list the tags available for the given identifier.

You may find the <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> command
(*et* similars) useful to insert the word under cursor. A map may help you with
it.

```
nnoremap \] :ts <c-r><c-w><CR>
```

Comment: Could you use <cword> in place of the control keys?

Comment: I tried 'nnoremap' with cword, but vim complains on cword. Here is my line from .vimrc:  nnoremap ^] :ts <cword><CR>    Although ^R^W instead works.

Comment: @Mark: Hmm, the `<cword>` thing is an command line expansion, so it might be better to keep it in command line things indeed. I rolled back to version 1 of the answer.